# Using Scala reflection to create a object of its declared class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala and I have difficulties writing a spark-sql application to dynamically load user classes and map rdds to it.

```
   rdd.map(line => {  
        val cls = Class.forName("UserClass")  
        val constructor = cls.getConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[String])  
        Tuple1(constructor.newInstence(line._1, line._2)).asInstanceOf[cls.type]  
    }).toDF()
```

The problem is converting the object to its declared class, as cls.type returns java.lang.class[_], which is not expected. At runtime the following exception would be threw:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type java.lang.class[_] is not supported
```

BTW, I'm using Scala 2.10 and spark 1.6.1.
Any suggestions and comments would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you compile and/or run this code? And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks for your notice, I've added the exception message. I just expect the object to be of its declared class, not Any or Class[T].

Comment: I really wonder what kind of problem you are trying to solve using this approach. Could you explain your requirements?

Comment: We have logs of different schema in Kafka (maybe more in the future), and they have a common field user_id. Now we want to apply a 'select distinct user_id' function to each log, so the data processing is suitable for each log. That's why I'm trying to dynamically load the schema for RDD.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a solution, but I can tell you some things you're doing wrong.

You wrap an object in a `Tuple1` and then you try to cast the tuple to a different type, instead of the object itself.

`cls.type` is not the type that the `Class` `cls` represents. It is the type of the variable `cls`, which in this case happens to be `java.lang.Class[_]`.

Casting is mainly a compile time thing. So you can only cast to types that are known at compile time. You say that you are dynamically loading classes, so I guess that they are not known to the compiler.

Comment: If runtime casting is not supported, I'm afraid that I was wrong at the first place. Thank you all the same.

Comment: The thing is, I think the runtime type doesn't matter here. The exception seems to indicate that Spark uses the compile time type to determine whether an operation is supported or not. If it was the runtime type that matters, you would not need to cast. But I'm no Spark expert.